# Adding probability without adding more to StringArray

Tags: java, random, probability, arrays

I got this `string[]` I use in a grid of these images. The grid is generated randomly using a random. now I use the way of just adding the one object more times. but my algorithm to regenerate one if two pictures are the same(eg. egg-tree-blackcar-blackcar-pinkcar) won't work because I check the array indexes of the images.

```
String bingoObject[] = {  
    "black_car",  
    "gray_car",  
    "white_car",  
    "red_car",  
    "yellow_car",  
    "blue_car",  
    "pink_car",  
    "green_car",  
    "boat",  
    "tree",  
    //ADDED MORE FOR CHANCES  
    "black_car",
    "black_car",  
    "gray_car",   
    "white_car",  
    "red_car",  
    "blue_car",  
    "green_car"
};
```

Is there another way to get randoms and assigning probability to each object without having to add them more times into the array? This would clean and help me through a lot of messy coding.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737283/weighted-randomness-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't personally know of any ways to assign probability, but we can kind of create our own way.  It's not the most efficient way of doing so, but it does create a pseudo-probability.

```
        int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int index = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
        {
            index = index + rnd.nextInt(numbers.length);
        }
        index=index/3;

        System.out.println(numbers[index]);
```

This will skew the array index to be somewhere near the middle, most of the time.  So the most common values, in theory, will be near the middle of the array, while the borders will be very uncommon.

You can change the "3" value to be whatever you want, the higher this number is, the more middle-biased the numbers should be.

Upon running this 10 times, my values were:
2,6,7,2,6,5,6,6,4,5

Comment: interesting way of going through this, i will try it. so by moving the items i want to be most probable of getting, i put in the middle of the StringArray? Thanks!