# Randomly select numbers in a range from a specified probability distribution

Tags: java, random, range

I want to select a random number from ranges such as 3-10 or 4-6. The numbers should be selected such that the lower the number the more chance it has to be selected. My code below only selects each number with an equal probability.

```
private int bonusPoints;
private double randomBonusPoints = Math.Random() * 100;

bonusPoints = (int)randomBonusPoints;
```

How do I select from a distribution such as `P(3,4,5)=85%, P(6,7,8)=10%, P(9,10)=5%`?

Comment: Do you have a specific distribution in mind?

Comment: 3 to 5 common (85%) 6-8 rare (10%) 9-10 super rare (5%). That type of distribution you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737283/weighted-randomness-in-java

Comment: Thanks Assylias, I'll check it out.

Comment: Shiroi, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your distribution is likely to change, so you don't want to hard-code your distribution in the way Kevin's answer does, you can use a [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) with the [`ceilingEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#ceilingEntry(K)) method. This allows you to assign a weight to a selection option. You can then generate a random number from 0 to the sum of the weights. The output is then statistically as per your weighted distribution.

The code to select an entry, once the map is created, is very short:

```
Random rand = new Random();
...
double rnd = rand.nextDouble() * totalWeight;
int elem = map.ceilingEntry(rnd).getValue();
```

To create an arbitrary distribution you do something like:

```
int[] options = new int[]{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
double[] weights = new double[]{ 0.85/3d, 0.85/3d, 0.85/3d,
                                 0.10/3d, 0.10/3d, 0.10/3d,
                                 0.05/2d, 0.05/2d };

NavigableMap<Double, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Double, Integer>();
double totalWeight = 0d;

for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    totalWeight += weights[i];
    map.put(totalWeight, options[i]);
}
```

Testing this over 10000 selections gave the following weightings:

```
03: 28.99% 
04: 28.10% 
05: 28.06% 
06: 3.27% 
07: 3.62% 
08: 3.08% 
09: 2.40% 
10: 2.48%
```

Test code:

```
//  select from the weighted elements
Random rand = new Random();
HashMap<Integer, Double> freqs = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
int iterations = 10000;
for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    double rnd = rand.nextDouble() * totalWeight;
    int elem = map.ceilingEntry(rnd).getValue();
    freqs.put(elem, (freqs.containsKey(elem) ? freqs.get(elem) : 0) + (1d/iterations));
}
Map<Integer, Double> sortedFreqs = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(freqs);

for(Map.Entry<Integer,Double> entry : sortedFreqs.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%02d: %.2f%% %n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() * 100d);
}
```

Comment: See my answer Andy, just populate an array according to frequency.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi. The OP listed a specific arbitrary frequency distribution in a comment on the question, which this answer returns, and yours does not ("*3 to 5 common (85%) 6-8 rare (10%) 9-10 super rare (5%).*").

Comment: Yes mine does, each subsequent number has a lower probability, 3 has the highest 10 has the lowest.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Yours returns a distribution with, for example, `P(3) = 22.222%`. The `P(3)` specified in the OP's comment was `28.333%`. It is unclear exactly which distribution the OP requires, hence me adding this alternative as with this you can model any arbitrary distribution very precisely without requiring long lists of the elements, or hardcoding a distribution with `if` statements.

Comment: @AndyBrown Thanks!, your answer is detailed and the code is not hardcoded, which is very handy since sometimes I'll be adding bigger ranges. Weight in this case is the percent chance of getting a certain number/item right?

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi. In this case it is the percentage (as per the distribution in your original comment). However you should note that the weights do not have to add up to 100%. The probability of choosing an item is simply: `itemWeight / totalWeight`

Comment: 0.05 = 5% but what does /2d means? is that to shorten the values? ive been noticing in my previous iteration of the program it gave me long doubles... very long ones.

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi. I only did that as you said that "9-10 (super-rare) 5%", which I took to mean that the probability of a 9 OR a 10 was 5%, so the probability of a 9 is 2.5%, and a 10 was the same. With this method you could set the weights in any way you like. e.g. for a probability of `x<sup>2</sup>`, you could do `totalWeight += Math.pow(options[i], 2);`

Comment: @AndyBrown, just a little thing which I find a bit funny, 10 has a bigger probability chance of being picked than 9 XD ahahaha

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi. That's just a sample run. Run it again and 10 might come out slightly less frequently than 9.

Comment: @AndyBrown yeah don't worry, I like the code snippet, it's easy to understand and it has a lot of power in it, and I say easy because I'm not a very experienced programmer, I dont even know about that navigableMap class, did you make it or is it inside java's libraries? if it is then I have to go and read XD

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi. It's `java.util.NavigableMap`. The javadoc link is in the answer.

Comment: @AndyBrown without a doubt your answer was by far the best of all the others posted, I could understand it after a few reads and it applies pretty good to my game, thanks for taking your time :) and teaching a newbie, I'll be picking it as my answer for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest (from an "understanding the code" perspective) way to do it:

```
int choice;
double r = Math.random();

if(r < .5){  //50% chance to choose 4
   choice = 4;
}
else if(r < .9){  //40% chance to choose 5
   choice = 5;
}
else{  //10% chance to choose 6
   choice = 6;
}
```

Obviously you can adjust for other numbers and other chances to choose those numbers, but this demonstrates the basics.

Also note that googling "weighted random number generator java" returns a ton of results, including a bunch of answers from StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh I'll try it out n.n.

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi That's how if/elseif statements work. If it fails the first if statement, you know r is above .5, so if the second one evaluates to true, then you know r is between .5 and .9, which gives you the 40% chance.

Comment: Yeah after giving it a bit more thought could see that, XD haha my bad, thanks!

Comment: I will wait 10 more minutes, if no one else gives a different answer I'll pick yours :)

Comment: I think that the smartest way would be to use a Poisson's law P and return `Math.round(P(Math.rand()))` but this solution is much easier to understand.

Comment: Arnaud, could you write the answer like Kevin? So I can rate it.

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi - Please wait a little longer that 10 minutes - please wait for the best answer.

Comment: @KevinWorkman another question, If I only want numbers from 2-13 to appear? it doesnt matter the chance, just a random number from the range between 2 and 13?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Or he could just change the accepted answer if a better one comes along...

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Ok I shall wait a bit more.

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi You really should consider googling a bit more. But the general formula is: min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1))

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi If you want a number between `2-13`, select a number between `0-11` and add 2. For my answer, sorry but I need time to do it right and I am currently at work. I will write it tonight (in 4h for me)

Comment: This approach is illogical, see my answer below where I use an array populated according to frequency.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The OP is clearly a novice, so I was going for the simplest code possible. Is it the best approach? Nope. But calling it **illogical** seems a bit unfair. But oh well, let the StackOverflow Pedantic Bickering (TM) start!

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the cruelty. But yes, I do feel that my answer actually mathematically creates a distribution in which the 3 has the highest probability and 10 has the lowest.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi And I'm not saying your answer is **wrong**. Just that mine is more suited to the OP, who is a novice programmer. Although looking at your answer now, it does seem a little goofy- why not just use an array of weights for each number?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Math.pow` on the initial random number provides a smooth scale without damaging the rendomness. Choosing your weight is open to debate but the results of this look ok. You can clearly scale it up or down too.

```
public long weightedRandom(long lowest, long highest, double weight) {
    // Even distribution r >= 0 and < 1.
    double r = Math.random();
    // Add the weight while we are still between 0 and 1.
    r = Math.pow(r, weight);
    // Scale it - r >= 0 and <= highest - lowest.
    r = r * (highest - lowest + 1);
    // Translate to lowest.
    r += lowest;
    // Floor to long.
    return (long) r;
}

private void test(double weight) {
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        results.add(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int r = (int) weightedRandom(0, results.size() - 1, weight);
        results.set(r, results.get(r) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Weight: " + weight + " Results: " + results);
}

public void test() {
    test(1);
    test(10);
    test(.1);
    test(2);
}
```

Results look like:

```
Weight: 1.0 Results: [119, 91, 112, 84, 96, 95, 86, 112, 93, 112]
Weight: 10.0 Results: [773, 57, 44, 37, 23, 15, 16, 9, 18, 8]
Weight: 0.1 Results: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 14, 76, 243, 659]
Weight: 2.0 Results: [331, 119, 100, 85, 87, 71, 53, 59, 48, 47]
```

Which looks like a scaling factor to me.

Comment: Thanks for posting your approach to this "problem" I had :) have an internet choco-cookie! may you have a nice day n.n

Comment: @ShiroiTamashi - Yum!