# How do I generate random integer using special distribution

Tags: java, random

Given random integers and probabilities, I want to write a java method to return one of the integers with the probability associated with that integer. Kindly advise. thanks!

Comment: Ok goahead. Let us know if you stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weighted randomness in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737283/weighted-randomness-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by converting uniform `[0, 1)` distribution produced by `Random#nextDouble()` to distribution adjusted to weights:

```
public int generateRandom(Random r, Map<Integer, Double> weights) {
    // find summary weight
    double s = weights.values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();  
    double f = r.nextDouble() * s;    // uniformly distributed value in range [0, s)
    for (Entry<Integer, Double> w : weights.entrySet()) {
        f -= w.getValue();
        if (f < 0)
            return w.getKey();
    }
    return -1;    // never happen if each weight >= 0 and summary weight > 0
}
```

And a testing method:

```
@Test
public void testGenerateRandom() {
    Random R = new Random();
    Map<Integer, Double> weights = new HashMap<>();

    freqs.put(0, 0d);    // weight of 0 is 0
    freqs.put(1, 0.5d);
    freqs.put(2, 0.5d);

    // assert that 0 and -1 are never generated
    assertFalse(IntStream.range(0, 1000000)
         .map(i -> generateRandom(R, weights))
         .filter(i -> i <= 0)   
         .findAny()
         .isPresent());
}
```