# Biased Random Number Generator - Java

Tags: java, random

I am looking for a random number generator that is biased towards giving numbers "furthest away" from a set of already selected numbers.  For example, if my range is [1, 50] and I pass in a set of numbers such as (1, 20, 40), then I would want the generator to "prefer" producing numbers further away from 1, 20, and 40.  Therefore, numbers such as 50 or 30 would be more likely to be drawn than 20 or 40.  I suspect that this may already exist.  Does anyone know of such an implementation that I can use for Java?

Comment: I dont know exactly how the Random class work, but i id actually a poor randomizer, you can take a look at jis weekness. It might be what you are looking for. we usaly prefer SecureRandom when real randomness is required.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737283/weighted-randomness-in-java

Comment: =/ "biased random number generator". Oh dear, I get this this bad feeling their might be an evil moneymaking scheme we are assisting with here. :P (jk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it by hand. Basically the idea is we take in some numbers we don't want to generate, then we generate a random number and if that number is in the list of numbers we don't want we try again up to a maximum number of retries.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int times = 25;
        int[] listOfNumbers = {1, 2, 3};
        int max = 5, min = 1;

        while(times-- > 0)
        {   
            System.out.print(GeneratePreferredNumbers(listOfNumbers, max, min) + " ");
        }


    }//main method

    public static Integer GeneratePreferredNumbers(int[] listOfNotPreffered, int max, int min)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum;
        int retry = 1; //increasing this lessons the likely of our non-preferred numbers to show up
        HashSet<Integer> notPrefer = new HashSet<>();

        //add all the numbers we don't want to generate into a HashSet for easy lookup
        for(int index = 0; index < listOfNotPreffered.length; index++)
            notPrefer.add(listOfNotPreffered[index]);

        do {
            randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            if(notPrefer.contains(randomNum))
            {
                retry--;
            }
            //we found a good value, let's return it
            else{
                retry = 0;
            }
        } while (retry > 0);

        return randomNum;
    }
```

Output:

retry = 0 (just simply random)

```
2 2 4 4 4 2 1 2 2 4 3 3 4 5 4 4 1 5 3 2 1 2 3 3 1
```

retry = 1

```
1 2 5 3 3 4 3 1 2 1 4 1 3 3 1 1 5 3 5 4 2 1 3 4 5
```

retry = 2

```
3 3 2 4 4 2 2 1 4 5 5 5 4 2 1 4 5 1 4 5 1 4 4 2 2
```

retry = 3

```
5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 2 4 5 5 1 4 5 4 3 5 4 4 4 5 3 1 2
```

retry = 4

```
5 4 5 4 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 1 5 2 5 5 5 2 4 5 5 2 4 4 4
```

retry = 5

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 4 5 4 4 5 4 5 4 5 5 5 5
```

NOTE: The more times we allow the algorithm to retry the more likely our output will consist of numbers we want. This allows you to control how likely you want those non-preferred numbers to show up. This makes sense because if we were to increase the retry to infinite, this would stop only when the number generated is not contained in our list non-preferred numbers.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [weighted random distribution](https://www.google.com/search?q=weighted%20random%20distribution), where some numbers are more likely than others.

The decision you have to make, is how the random distribution curve should look, i.e. how aggressively are the chosen numbers avoided.

As you pick new numbers, you also need to decide how long the avoidance lasts. E.g. is a previous number avoided equally for a particular number of picks, or does it fade out over time?

**Examples of distribution curves**

[image]
[image]
[image]

The last one shows a fade out, where `40` was three picks ago, `1` was two picks ago, and `20` was last pick, where numbers `18` to `22` (inclusive) have a 0% probability for the next pick.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something a bit different and found the following code useful:

```
package util.math.random;

import math.MersenneTwisterFast;

public class SigmoidBiasedDistribution {
    private MersenneTwisterFast mtf;
    private int min;
    private int max;
    private double minsigmoidscalefactor;
    private double maxsidmoidscalefactor;
    private double maxoffsetfactor;

public SigmoidBiasedDistribution(int min, int max, double minsigmoidscalefactor, double maxsidmoidscalefactor, double maxoffsetfactor) {
    this.mtf = new MersenneTwisterFast();
    this.minsigmoidscalefactor = minsigmoidscalefactor;
    this.maxsidmoidscalefactor = maxsidmoidscalefactor;
    this.maxoffsetfactor = maxoffsetfactor;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public int[] getPoints(int points) {
    int[] pts = new int[points];
    double lowoffset = mtf.nextDouble(true, true) * maxoffsetfactor;
    double highoffset = mtf.nextDouble(true, true) * maxoffsetfactor;
    double randomsigmoidscalefactor = mtf.nextDouble(true, true) * (maxsidmoidscalefactor - minsigmoidscalefactor) + minsigmoidscalefactor;
    System.out.println(randomsigmoidscalefactor);
    double pointsoffset = ((1 - highoffset) - lowoffset) / (points - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < points; i++) {
        double offset = (i * pointsoffset) + lowoffset;
        double scalefactor = getHalfSigmoid(offset, randomsigmoidscalefactor);
        pts[i] = (int) (scalefactor * (max - min)) + min;
    }
    return pts;
}

//sigmoid scale factor can range from -1 to 1 (-1 represents most aggressive initial slope, 1 represents least aggressive initial slope, 0 is linear)
//https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tswgrnoosy
public double getHalfSigmoid(double value, double sigmoidscalefactor) {
    return (value - value * sigmoidscalefactor) / (sigmoidscalefactor - 2 * Math.abs(value) * sigmoidscalefactor + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SigmoidBiasedDistribution sbd = new SigmoidBiasedDistribution(5, 80, 5, 0, 0.5, 0.2);
    int[] pts = sbd.getPoints(3);
    for(int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(pts[i]);
    }
}   
}
```

Basically the code just fits N equidistant points to a half sigmoid curve.  Alternatively, I also wrote up the following solution, but I like the solution above better for my purposes.

```
package util.math.random;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import math.MersenneTwisterFast;

public class WeightedRandomGenerator {
    private double sigmoidscalefactor;
    private MersenneTwisterFast mtf;
    private List<Integer> points;
    private int min;
    private int max;
    private int numcompletelyrandom;

public WeightedRandomGenerator(int min, int max, int numcompletelyrandom, double sigmoidscalefactor) {
    this.mtf = new MersenneTwisterFast();
    this.points = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.numcompletelyrandom = numcompletelyrandom;
    this.sigmoidscalefactor = sigmoidscalefactor;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    clear();
}

public int nextInt() {
    if(points.size() - 2 < numcompletelyrandom) {
        int nextint = mtf.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        points.add(nextint);
        return nextint;
    }
    else {
        int maxsep = getMaxSeparation();
        while(true) {
            int nextint = mtf.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            int nearestneighbor = getNearestNeighbor(nextint);
            double sepfrac = (double) nearestneighbor / (double) maxsep;
            if(mtf.nextBoolean(getHalfSigmoid(sepfrac))) {
                points.add(nextint);
                return nextint;
            }
        }
    }
}

private int getNearestNeighbor(int nextint) {
    int delta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        delta = Math.min(delta, Math.abs(nextint - points.get(i)));
    }
    return delta;
}

private int getMaxSeparation() {
    int maxsep = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
        int delta = points.get(i) - points.get(i-1);
        maxsep = Math.max(delta, maxsep);
    }
    return maxsep;
}

private void clear() {
    points.clear();
    points.add(min);
    points.add(max);
}

//sigmoid scale factor can range from -1 to 1 (-1 represents most aggressive initial slope, 1 represents least aggressive initial slope, 0 is linear)
//https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tswgrnoosy
public double getHalfSigmoid(double value) {
    return (value - value * sigmoidscalefactor) / (sigmoidscalefactor - 2 * Math.abs(value) * sigmoidscalefactor + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WeightedRandomGenerator wrg = new WeightedRandomGenerator(1, 80, 2, 0.95);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(wrg.nextInt());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to throw in one more idea for accomplishing this - a straightforward solution especially if you have a small number of possible outcomes.

Let's say you want to generate numbers 1 through 5 with a probabilities of 40% for 3, 20% for 2 and 4, and 10% for 1 and 5. You start with an unbiased random number from 1 through 10 and then use the following mapping to get the desired biased number:

| Generated Number | Biased Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2..3 | 2 |
| 4..7 | 3 |
| 8..9 | 4 |
| 10 | 5 |

For instance, this code...

```
int[] count = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int sample_size = 10000;
for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int rnd = random.nextInt(10) + 1;

    if (rnd == 1) count[0]++;
    else if (rnd >= 2 && rnd <= 3) count[1]++;
    else if (rnd >= 4 && rnd <= 7) count[2]++;
    else if (rnd >= 8 && rnd <= 9) count[3]++;
    else if (rnd == 10) count[4]++;
}
    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Percentage of outcome %d is %.2f%%.",
                                     i + 1,
                                     100f * count[i] / sample_size
                                    ));
}
```

... produces the following output:

```
Percentage of outcome 1 is 10.14%.
Percentage of outcome 2 is 19.89%.
Percentage of outcome 3 is 40.03%.
Percentage of outcome 4 is 19.59%.
Percentage of outcome 5 is 10.35%.
```