# Choosing random value from list based on it's percentage that keeps changing

Tags: java, dictionary

so I am working on a project where I need to guess the historical period an author is in. The authors are selected randomly. I was thinking of making a dictionary which would contain all the historical periods, and then put a list with values as the key. I want to do it so everytime I get him right, a counter for that author will go up. After that, he should be less likely to be picked.

Example:

dictionary- periodOne: List(Author1, Author2), periodTwo: List(Author3, Author4)

Author1 gets picked. I guess correctly. The author will have a number assigned to him somehow and this number will be increased by one now. Next author is being picked. Author1 was already picked so he has smaller chance of being picked, however he can still be picked.

I was thinking of making maybe dictionary with the number values and then putting this dictionary into it as the value (Don't know if that is even possible)

Any ideas on how to do this effectively?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think this will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083623/decreasing-chance-of-choosing-a-number-from-a-list-of-consecutive-numbers) it's the same just concept just with numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a logic question, so I'll show you the logic.

We're assuming you create a `Map` with the author name (or author index) as the key and a count as the value.  Each time the author is selected, the count goes up by 1.

You need to keep or calculate two values.  The total count for all authors plus the total number of authors and the largest count for any author.

The total count is used to get a random integer between 0 and (total count - 1).  You would use the `Random` class to get this `int`.

Now, you iterate through the `Map`, using the `Iterator` class.  For each author, you calculate the selection value.

```
selection value = maximum count - author count + 1;
```

Next, you sum the selection value.

Next, you compare the summed selection value with your random number.  As soon as the summed selection value is greater than the random number, you back up one author.  That author is the randomly selected author.

The higher an author count gets, the less likely that author will be selected.  But, it's still possible.  Since it's random, the same author can be selected twice or more times in a row.  Not likely, but possible.