# Java "fake" math.random()

Tags: java, random, numbers

I need a function which generates me random numbers but where some numbers can appear more often then others.

Lets say i want random numbers from 1 to 10 where 2 and 3 have twice the chance to appear than the rest.

How can i do this in java? 
Haven`t found a function for this.

Edit: Code i have so far (Which was a compromise solution, i know it`s not what i want)

```
int min;
int max;
double min1;
double max1;
for(int j=0;j<Ammount_numbers;j++) {
            if(min1==0) {
                  min1= min + (Math.random() * (max+1-min));
                  max1= min + (Math.random() * (max+1-min));
            }

            double randomnumber = min1 + (Math.random() * ((max1-min1) + 1));
}
```

Min and Max are the borders (1 to 10 in the example)
And with min1 and max1 i generated new, smaller borders so that the randomnumber is clustered in a random range.. 
And as i said: i know that this is not what i wanted, it was just a compromise solution so i could work with it..

Comment: Where is the code which you tried so far so that we could check that for bugs and problems?

Comment: no such ready function. Must write youself

Comment: fill an array and randomize the index number, adding more 2's and 3's.

Comment: @RickAstley you are making him dependable upon others to think. Best thing is encourage him to think himself. Isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weighted randomness in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737283/weighted-randomness-in-java)

Comment: @TahirHussainMir: you first comment is irrelevant. The OP is clearly asking how-to.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I respect your opposition. But SO mentions opinion based should not be answered. Am i right? if not, please enlighten me.

Comment: @Vanna: the comment by Tahir was not formulated this way.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir: the question is certainly not opinion-based. There are well-established techniques which are objectively appropriate. If you want to close the question, the "too broad" tag would be more appropriate (but undeserved IMO)

Comment: i edited what i had so far. i don't need a real "how to". giving me an idea on how to do it is enough cause at the moment i don`t have an idea

Comment: @Vanna: I know this very well and I have know SO's policy for years, this is not the point. Tahir did not explain this. This question can be answered without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a generator of a discrete random variable with prescribed probabilities, a well-known technique is to fill an array with the cumulated probabilities. The values will fit in range [0,1].

Then perform uniform drawings and identify the subinterval where the value falls, by dichotomic search (linear can do for a small array).

The subinterval index will follow the desired distribution.

Comment: Yes. It was a stupid down vote. Still don't know why someone downvoted this. Atleast, he/she must have commented.

Comment: Okay the first part is clear to me. But what do you mean with "uniform drawings..."?

Comment: @Grogak: using the uniform random number generator. http://keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
Now there is a 50 % chance of getting a 2 or 3

```
a=(Math.random() * 7) + 4;
b=(Math.random() * 2 ) + 2; // math.random() within a range.
x=Math.random()* 1;
if(x==0){
// print a;
}
else if(x==1){
// print b;
}
```

Comment: i have just used the concept of Math.random() within the range. this is an excellent article on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained

Answer (score 0):

Set up the numbers you want at the correct frequencies in an array and pick a random entry from the array.

```
Random rand = new Random();

// ...

int specialRandom() {
  int[] selections = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  return selections[rand.nextInt(selections.length)];
}
```

For more complex selection, use the desired frequency, pick a random frequency and return the matching number.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that with Math.random() itsself, but you could write your own random() method, which uses Math.random() and returns your own random numbers according to your own scale.