# Normalizing random in Java based on associated weights

Tags: java, random

I have some tasks with some weights associated with them:

```
Task1:4
Task2:10
Task3:15
Task4:1
Task5:8
Task6:3
Task7:25
Task8:12
Task9:4
Task10:12
Task11:12
Task12:10
Task13:12
Task14:20
Task15:12
Task16:12
```

The sum of weights is not necessarily equal to 100. In above case its 172.

I am using the `RandomCollection` class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409791/887235)

I have just added the following method to `RandomCollection` for fetching the map generated:

```
public NavigableMap<Double, E> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
```

This is my test class:

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.util.Map;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RandomCollection<String> randomCollection = new RandomCollection<String>();

        randomCollection.add(4 * 1.0/172, "Task1");
        randomCollection.add(10 * 1.0/172, "Task2");
        randomCollection.add(15 * 1.0/172, "Task3");
        randomCollection.add(1 * 1.0/172, "Task4");
        randomCollection.add(8 * 1.0/172, "Task5");
        randomCollection.add(3 * 1.0/172, "Task6");
        randomCollection.add(25 * 1.0/172, "Task7");
        randomCollection.add(12 * 1.0/172, "Task8");
        randomCollection.add(4 * 1.0/172, "Task9");
        randomCollection.add(12 * 1.0/172, "Task10");
        randomCollection.add(12 * 1.0/172, "Task11");
        randomCollection.add(10 * 1.0/172, "Task12");
        randomCollection.add(12 * 1.0/172, "Task13");
        randomCollection.add(20 * 1.0/172, "Task14");
        randomCollection.add(12 * 1.0/172, "Task15");
        randomCollection.add(12 * 1.0/172, "Task16");

        for (Map.Entry<Double, String> entry : randomCollection.getMap().entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " : " + entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

I am multiplying by 1.0 for getting a double and dividing by 172 to normalize.

The output of above program is:

```
Task1 : 0.023255813953488372
Task2 : 0.08139534883720931
Task3 : 0.16860465116279072
Task4 : 0.17441860465116282
Task5 : 0.22093023255813957
Task6 : 0.23837209302325585
Task7 : 0.38372093023255816
Task8 : 0.4534883720930233
Task9 : 0.47674418604651164
Task10 : 0.5465116279069767
Task11 : 0.6162790697674418
Task12 : 0.6744186046511628
Task13 : 0.7441860465116279
Task14 : 0.8604651162790697
Task15 : 0.9302325581395349
Task16 : 1.0
```

Is this correct ?

I want `RandomCollection.next()` to return me a Task between `Task1` and `Task16`; but as per its importance or associated weights. i.e. if I call `RandomCollection.next()` 172 times, 4 times `Task1` should be returned, 10 times `Task2` should be returned and so on.

Comment: Let's do that differently, if you add 172 tasks in your collections (could be the same object if you use a list) you just need to pick one. So add 4 times Task1, 10 times Task2 etc in a list, Collections.shuffle it and take the first element

Comment: @RC. This is simpler if you only do it rarely, but astonishingly more expensive.

Comment: @PeterLawrey do rarely what, the OP probably need **one** shuffle, so I don't see what's expensive

Comment: @RC I agree, but if the OP only ever needs one result, the OP can add them to a list and select a random one rather than shuffling all 172 values.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's not what I meant, OP can shuffle then take element at index 0,1,2,3 etc no need to reshuffle. Anyways, the OP now has all cards in hand :)

Comment: @RC the OP can shuffle the items and take the first, each time OR the OP can select one at random. Shuffling once and selecting more than once is only appropriate if you want to remove that item from the collection as you go.

Comment: @PeterLawrey **OR** the OP can shuffle **once** and take the first item then the second one then the third one, etc

Comment: @RC. except that changes the distribution based on items already taken so it is not the same thing. e.g. If the distribution is random and independant, you can get two Task4 in a row.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP need something similar to a deck of card, you shuffle it once and deal cards, when every cards are served, then you have some exact distribution (i.e. you cannot have 5 aces). But maybe I didn't understand the question. Anyway, let's stop chitchatting in comments

Comment: My understanding is that the OP need something similar to a deck of card, you shuffle it once and deal cards, when every cards are served, then you have some exact distribution (i.e. you cannot have 5 aces). But maybe I didn't understand the question. Anyway, let's stop chitchatting in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weights are already normalised, so you can just add them naturally.

```
RandomCollection<String> randomCollection = 
    new RandomCollection<String>()
        .add(4,  "Task1")
        .add(10, "Task2")
        .add(15, "Task3")
        .add(1,  "Task4")
        .add(8,  "Task5")
        .add(3,  "Task6")
        .add(25, "Task7")
        .add(12, "Task8")
        .add(4,  "Task9")
        .add(12, "Task10")
        .add(12, "Task11")
        .add(10, "Task12")
        .add(12, "Task13")
        .add(20, "Task14")
        .add(12, "Task15")
        .add(12, "Task16");
```

The cumulative probability looks about right.