# Getting a random number (with a percentage for a specific range)

Tags: java, random

I'm generating random numbers between 1-100, and I just want to know if its possible to set a bigger percentage to get some numbers.
For example: The range is 1-100, but i want that there will be a 70% chance to get a number between 40-50.

Comment: If you need help with questions like this, it is very helpful for the people you ask to show us what you have tried so far and also to show us your code in a minimalistic example, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: you can create random number between 0 and 1, and if it reaches above 0,7 then you just can generate between 40 and 50. Else generate 1-100

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409652/random-weighted-selection-in-java

Comment: @mlecz or rather, between 1-90, and then adjust. Otherwise, you'll get numbers between 40 and 50 again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random weighted selection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409652/random-weighted-selection-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a computer science problem, but a probability theory one. Programming languages generally provide pseudo random number generators that follow the uniform distribution. Based on the *probability integral transform* these can always be converted to a distribution of your choice.

You need a transform function from the uniform distribution in the range [0,100] to the distribution of your choice in the same range. Then you keep drawing numbers from the uniform distribution (that programming languages provide) and map resulting values using the transform function.

Check e.g. the following articles:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any code so I will not do that either :)

To solve this, use a longer range. If your random number is above your requested range, recalculate it so it fits in the range.

In your case, use the range 1-300. If <=100, use the original number. If >100, substract 100, divide by 200 (300-100), multiply by 10 (50-40), add 40 (to get inside the range).

And why is 300 the answer? In the range 1-100, 90 numbers are outside the 41-50 range. Since you want 70% of the numbers to be inside that range, the 90 outsiders are 30% of your total population. 30% is 90, means that 100% is 90/0,3=300