# Java: I am trying to generate a word with random characters and then checking it against a hashmap of words to see if it is real

Tags: random

So, I am trying to generate a word and then check if it is a real word using word index. Can someone help me figure out how to solve this, it is constantly giving me a never-ending loop. I just simply wanted to create random characters, and after each character see if it exists in the hashmap. First by checking to find the **key** which is the first letter of the word, and then by checking the substring of each word in that key selection.

```
  public ArrayList<String> randomSize(int length) {
            ArrayList<String> randomWords = new ArrayList<>(length);
            String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            // for loop add a new slot into randomWords
            for (int eachSlot = 0; eachSlot < length; eachSlot++) {
                // for each slot generate a random length for the word
                int randWordLength = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);
                // every slot generate a random firstLetter
                int slotFound = 0;
                String firstConfirmedLetter = "";
                // while the first letter is not found in WordIndex
                while (slotFound == 0) {
                    int randNumer = (int) (Math.random() * (24 - 0) + 0);
                    String firstLetter = letters.substring(randNumer, randNumer + 1);
                    if (wordIndex.containsKey(firstLetter) == true)
                    {
                        firstConfirmedLetter = firstLetter;
                        randomWords.add(firstConfirmedLetter);
                        System.out.println(firstLetter);// working
                        randWordLength--;
                        slotFound = 1;
                        // if it is found end the while loop
                    }
    
                }
    
                // we found the first letter, now we need to find the rest of the letters
                for (int eachLetter = 0; eachLetter < randWordLength; eachLetter++){
                    int isFound = 0;
                    // while letter is not found loop through until it is found with combimation to the previous letter
                    while (isFound == 0){
                        // gerate a random letter
                        int randLetter = (int) (Math.random() * (24 - 0) + 0);
                        String nextLetter = letters.substring(randLetter, randLetter + 1);
                        //create curr word
                        String currWord = randomWords.get(eachSlot) + nextLetter;// works until here
                        // loop through each word in wordIdex to find match
                        System.out.println(wordIndex.get(firstConfirmedLetter).size());
                        for(int i = 0; i< wordIndex.get(firstConfirmedLetter).size(); i++){
                            String test = wordIndex.get(firstConfirmedLetter).get(i);
                            if(test.length() > eachLetter+2){
                              System.out.println(test.substring(0,eachLetter+2));
                              if(test.substring(0,eachLetter+2).equals(currWord)){
                                  String currState = randomWords.get(eachSlot);
                                  randomWords.set(eachSlot,currWord);
                                  isFound =1;
                              }
                            }
                        }
    
                    }
                }
    
    
    
            }
            return randomWords;
        }
```

Comment: You underestimate the universe of existing words.

Comment: You can actually use more than one method to solve your problem.  Creating a semi-random word consisting of 5 letters, where letters 1, 3, and 5 are consonants and letters 2 and 4 are vowels might get you a hit if you let the program run over a weekend.

Answer (score 1):

The odds of generating a valid word randomly are low, so this approach is inefficient. Instead, randomly select a valid word from your dictionary:

```java
private final List<String> words = wordIndex.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

public List<String> randomSize(int length) {
  Collections.shuffle(words);
  return new ArrayList<>(words.subList(0, length));
}
```

Your code is very difficult to read and therefore difficult to fix, but here are some bugs in it:

- The `randWordLength` chosen can be zero, but this will still result in a one character word being selected. I presume you intended to select words of length 1–10, inclusive.
- You only randomly choose from the first 24 letters of your 26-letter set. Presumably, your dictionary contains words with all 26 letters, but these can never be found.
- Most importantly, you are testing prefixes of words of any length, but you keep looping until you find a word of the specified length. As a simplified example, consider a dictionary of two words, "ab" and "acc". If a length of three is required, but the loop chooses the prefix "ab", it will loop forever, trying to find a three-letter word that starts with "ab".

You must match prefixes *only* against words of the required length.

Comment: yeah I already did that. But would how know how I could do an efficient way of generating a word and checking it with my dictionary? Thanks

Comment: @Nexteon The only way to get more efficient with a generative strategy is to make it less random. For example, you could use [a Markov process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) to increase the probability of choosing a valid letter based on previously chosen letters. This doesn't eliminated random generation entirely, but it's like using weighted dice to improve your odds.

Answer (score -1):

You underestimate the universe of existing words.
There are: 24^10 possibilities, that is 3.6520347e16  possible words.  It's not infinite if you let it running long enough, is just a terrible strategy.

You could increase the probability for early positives by combining random weighted generation like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409791/1803810 , with a distribution based on the frequency of the appearance of letters in english [http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html).

Comment: If you fix the bugs, it's actually not that slow (milliseconds per word).

Comment: Even if 1 milisecond, (it's probably around 20), 3.6520347e16 possible generated words, to find one of the 171,476 in english, means, if uniformly distributed, the first word will be found in the first 3 years

Comment: No. I am talking about the code in the question. It isn't generating random character sequences and then checking whether they are in the dictionary. A letter is only added to the word being built if it is a prefix of a valid word. So (with bugs fixed), the code in question outputs a word in a fraction of a second.